# Open http deep link on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

How to open my app on iOS when user open a URL http link like a http://myappname.com/.
Can I use Firebase Dynamic Link or it fit only for URL like a https://myappname.page.link?

Comment: You can use your App Store link. That will direct the user to the page where they can download your app and if they have downloaded it, they can open it from there. Anyways, your question needs more detail as I can't be sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase dynamic links with custom domain(http://myappname.com/).

You are not limited to URL like a https://myappname.page.link.

[Setup custom domain for Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains)

Comment: When i add http://myappname.com/ to Firebase Dynamic Links, i need to change A record in DNS. I cant do this, because http://myappname.com/ its working website.